# Using the remote function with an AJAX request on the Jquery Validation

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, json, validation

I am using the Jquery Validation library to validate my registration form. Everything works but I am trying to use AJAX to see if a username exists in the database. The ajax request works but it seems to always evaluate true which tells me the username is already taken. I can't find much documentation on the remote function so I am stuck. My code is as follows.

```
<input type ='text'placeholder='Username' name="username" id="username" >
```

Jquery File

```
 $("#listener-register").validate({
  rules: {
      username: {
        required: true,
        remote: "http://... /check_username.php"
           }, ....
```

PHP File

```
if(isset($_POST["username"]))
{

 $con = new mysqli(...);

//received username value from registration page
 $username =  $mysqli->real_escape_string ($_POST["username"]); 

 //check username in db
 $results = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM ... WHERE username='$username'");

  $username_exist = mysqli_num_rows($results); //records count

 //if returned value is more than 0, username is not available


 if($username_exist) {
    die('Username Not Available, Please Choose Another!');
 }else{
    die('Username Is Available');
  }
 }
```

Thanks in advance for any help!!

Answer (score 0):

mysqli_num_rows return number 0 or more in that way it will return true always

```
if($username_exist == 1) {
    die('Username Not Available, Please Choose Another!');
 }else{
    die('Username Is Available');
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 if($username_exist > 0) { //denotes there is a similar username already present in the database
    die('Username Not Available, Please Choose Another!');
 }else{
    die('Username Is Available');
  }
 }
```

The reason we don't compare `($username_exists == 1)` is because this condition will fail if there are more than one matching usernames (though such a condition is less likely to arise but even so to be on the safer side.) hence check if greater than 0